# USB PNP sound device, microphone input not recognized, Lubuntu

Tags: usb, sound, lubuntu, microphone, soundcard

I purchased a used USB pnp sound device, it is a USB stick with a mic input and headset output, both jacks seem to be 3.5mm.

I tested it in Windows and in and out sound worked. It recognized the mic and played my voice on playback over a headset.

But when I try it on my Lubuntu machine, it does not pick up the mic.

It does however recognize the sound card, and play the output audio. Just not the mic which is actually exactly what I need it for.

Here's some info that I hope helps, not sure what else to give you for info, let me know.

PulseAudio VolumeControl> configuration> Prifile:
Analog stereo output + analog mono input
Analog stereo output
Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Mono Input [this started appearing today, not sure why it was not an option 2 days ago]
Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output
Analog mono input

---

`uname -a` gives me

```
Linux <USER> 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:10 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfea38000 irq 25
 1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                      Generic USB PnP Sound Device at usb-0000:00:1d.1-1, full speed
```

---

Thank you!